# Playing the same lottie animation when clicking on different containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, lottie

I'm looking for a way to play the same lottie animation on click on different containers, but can't seem to get it work. How can I do it?

Here's the sample code:

```js
$('.lottie-container').on('click', function() {
  playlottie($(this));
})

function playlottie(lottiecontainer) {
  var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: lottiecontainer,
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    path: "https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_rd4wrn81.json"
  });
  animation.goToAndPlay(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.5.3/lottie_svg.min.js"></script>

<div class="lottie-container">container1</div><br>
<div class="lottie-container">container2</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using `playlottie(this);` You are passing  jquery object not an regular fetched element?

Comment: @ikiK i've just tried, it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Its because of script plugin error i think.

You can see that you get the object by your function.

```js
$('.lottie-container').on('click', function() {
  playlottie($(this));
})

function playlottie(lottiecontainer) {
  console.log($(lottiecontainer).text());
  var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: $(lottiecontainer),
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    path: "https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_rd4wrn81.json"
  });
  animation.goToAndPlay(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.5.3/lottie_svg.min.js"></script>

<div class="lottie-container">container1</div><br>
<div class="lottie-container">container2</div>
```